# How generics helping in this scenario?

Tags: java, generics

Going through generics  at [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) and got this  question

```
public class Box<T> {
    // T stands for "Type"
    private T t;

    public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
    public T get() { return t; }
}
```

If i want box to hold only integer i can initiate like below . Makes sense here.

```
 Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
```

**case 2:-**
But at various place i have seen following below pattern

```
public class Box<Integer> {
    private Integer var;

    public void set(Integer var) { this.var = var; }
    public Integer get() { return var; }

}
```

The way of instantiation is same i.e

```
   Box<Integer> integerBox = new Box<Integer>();
```

But how instantiating with integer helps here as we are not using it ?

I am not getting what benefit we are getting with generic specifier  along with class declaration **in second case?**

I mean if i declare class without diamond operator in second case, what the benefit i am losing ? I am sure i am but not hitting the right spot .

**Edit :-**

Looks like i was not clear in case 2 snippet. Please refer below code snippet

```
public class Box<Integer> {
    private String var;

    public void set(String var) { this.var = var; }
    public String get() { return var; }

}
```

Comment: For fun, try `Box<String>` in your second example. Or `Box<Anything>`.

Comment: If you mean during instantiation . Yes i can't . But how it helps?

Comment: For you to realize that `public class Box<T>` is no different than `public class Box<Integer>`.

Comment: Thats what i am not able to understand. Becoz in case of public class Box<T> we can use T down in the class but what about public class Box<Integer> ?

Comment: You've just replaced `T` with `Integer`. `Integer` is not a reserved keyword.

Comment: You're just referring to your generic type parameter by the name `Integer` instead of `T`. It has no relation to the class `Integer`.

Comment: see my latest edit in second case

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i updated my case 2 code and hope i am clear now what i am trying to ask ?

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question. It invalidates what has been said. Instead, append to it.

Comment: Ok i will follow your advice now onwards. Hope you get my confusion now

Comment: (You should change it back now.) Well, no. In one case you use the type parameter. In the other you don't.

Comment: Done. Now please have reply on my edit part

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Looks like what you are trying to say Integer in private Integer var referring to <Integer> which is not reserved type integer but a object that is coming at run time. Right ?  If that is that case what if i want to use actual integer about somewhere as instance variable? Do i need to explicitly call it by fully qualified name i.e java.lang.integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see at "various places" is just bad coding. `Integer` in

```
public class Box<Integer>
```

is not a reference to the `java.lang.Integer` class, but a generic type variable, just like `T` was. As such, **it shadows `java.lang.Integer` type inside the class definition**. In fact, the two snippets you posted are exactly the same.

Just run the following piece of code, if you are not convinced:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Box<String> a = new Box<>();
        a.set("dummy");
        a.whatami();
    }
}

class Box<Integer> {
    private Integer var;

    public void whatami() {
        System.out.println(var.getClass().getName());
    }

    public void set(Integer var) { this.var = var; }
    public Integer get() { return var; }
}
```

Output will be `java.lang.String`, not `java.lang.Integer`.

In fact, you are not required to name the generic type `T`. You can call it `Foo`, `Bar`, `Baz`. Maybe avoiding misleading names could be a good idea. *Maybe*.

EDIT: your edit completely changes the question. In that specific case, you get no advantage from declaring a generic that does not use the generic type variable. Neither you get any disavantage, because of compile time type erasure.

**But**, it's not completely pointless. **Although the class does not use the type tag now, it might use it in a future version**. And if you get to the a point where you need to make your class generic, you will have to go through all the code you wrote until that moment and amend it with the diamond notation. It will cost you time and you might also have to refactor certain parts.

Comment: please see my updated code in case 2 where i am using String type for var but initializing with  Integer. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Looks like what you are trying to say Integer in  private Integer var referring to <Integer> which is not reserved type integer but a object that is coming at run time. Right ?

Comment: If that is that case what if i want to use actual integer about somewhere as instance variable? Do i need to explicitly call it by fully qualified name i.e java.lang.integer

Comment: Not at runtime, but at compile time. Yes, you can use `java.lang.Integer`, but _not_ using `Integer` as a type tag is much a better approach. See the edit.

Comment: now got you. But you said "using Integer as a type tag is much a better approach." But i have seen some of the core java classes using this . For example :-  private static class CaseInsensitiveComparator
implements Comparator<String>

Comment: Nope, that's not the same. `private static class CaseInsensitiveComparator implements Comparator<String>` means that `CaseInsensitiveComparator` (the class you are defining) implements the `Comparator` generic interface on `String` type. You can then use a `CaseInsensitiveComparator` wherever a `Comparator<String>` is required and/or assign ìt to variable with `Comparator<String>` static type. You can't write `CaseInsensitiveComparator<SomethingElse>`.